# JQuery, selecting what does NOT contains something

Tags: jquery, contains

If i want to select what contains "pc" i use `$('tr:contains("pc")')`

But what can i use to select what does NOT contains "pc"?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use the  [:not() selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) that is part of the jquery framework.  Something like `$('tr:not(:contains("pc"))')` should do the trick.

Comment: This is the one that I ended up using, thanks a lot.

Actually, I cheated :3 I was not using Jquery, but phpquery, and I was having problems using the .not function.

Comment: `:not` is actually standard css. It's `:contains` that's jquery specific.

Answer (score 5):

```
$('tr').not(':contains("pc")')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('tr:not(:contains("pc"))') // this can be used
```

Answer (score 0):

$("tr:not(:contains("pc"))")

if you use simple quotes with double quotes mixed in the same sentence, it doesn't work